# python pyglet and opengl

Tags: python, opengl, ubuntu-12.04, pyglet

I am trying to get 3D capabilities through python and have download pyglet. While going through the first example in this [tutorial](http://greendalecs.wordpress.com/2012/04/21/3d-programming-in-python-part-1/#comments) I got a bunch of strange errors that I cannot discern. The following is the script I am trying to run:

```
import pyglet

win = pyglet.window.Window()

@win.event
def on_draw():
    win.clear()

pyglet.app.run()
```

2 The following is the output I received from the python interpreter after I imported my script:

```
>>> import test as t
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    pyglet.app.run()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyglet/app/__init__.py", line 264, in run
    EventLoop().run()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyglet/app/xlib.py", line 93, in run
    sleep_time = self.idle()
  Fihttp://greendalecs.wordpress.com/2012/04/21/3d-programming-in-python-part-1/#commentsle "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyglet/app/__init__.py", line 193, in idle        
    window.dispatch_event('on_draw')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 1219, in dispatch_event
    EventDispatcher.dispatch_event(self, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyglet/event.py", line 340, in dispatch_event
    if handler(*args):
  File "test.py", line 13, in on_draw
    pyglet.app.run()
NameError: global name 'GL_COlOR_BUFFER_BIT' is not defined
```

1. How can I fix these errors? I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Emacs 24.3.
2. I have downloaded pyglet, through `apt-get install` but is there anything else I needed to do? Perhaps I do not have drivers configured or I need different software.

If you need more information let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GL_COlOR_BUFFER_BIT` is undefined, because the value you are looking for is called `GL_CO`**L**`OR_BUFFER_BIT`...

Comment: I just did this: `pip install PyOpenGL PyOpenGL_accelerate` and everything works now...

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, as of Pyglet 1.1.4, this is because 1.1.4 no longer supports "recent" versions of Mac OS.

However, the most recent non-released version of Pyglet DOES support, with a full new interface using Cocoa. So, until Pyglet 1.2 is released, you have to install Pyglet directly from the trunk, using e.g.

```
pip install --upgrade http://pyglet.googlecode.com/archive/tip.zip
```