# NameError: global name 'EventLoop' is not defined - pyglet

Tags: python, python-2.7, nameerror, pyglet, event-loop

I am trying to have python play an audio file for me. I am writing my code in enthought canopy.

```
import pyglet

sound = pyglet.media.load('song.wav')
sound.play()
pyglet.app.run()
```

When I run this I get an error: NameError: global name 'EventLoop' is not defined 
Also, the audio file plays the first note before the program errors.

I have no idea what is going on.

p.s. Do I need the pylab backend to be interactive for pyglet?

OS - osx 10.12.1
pyglet version 1.1.4-3

Traceback

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/name/Documents/name/Arduino Projects/python/Audio Testing.py in <module>()
      3 sound = pyglet.media.load('s.wav')
      4 sound.play()
----> 5 pyglet.app.run()

/Users/name/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyglet/app/__init__.pyc in run()
    262 
    263     '''
--> 264     EventLoop().run()
    265 
    266 def exit():

NameError: global name 'EventLoop' is not defined
```

Comment: Could you post the full traceback verbatim?

Comment: may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033227/python-pyglet-and-opengl

Comment: PyLab - No, you don't need that to be interactive. I'm wondering what OS and version of Pyglet you got installed?

Comment: I  added all that information to the question above

Comment: Make sure you haven't named any of your files the same thing as an important library module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the error but was unable to, although this library seems like it has a few other bugs too.

I did find that using the latest version of the library worked much better. My suggestion is to bump your version from `1.1.4` to `1.2.4`.

```
pip uninstall pyglet
pip install pyglet==1.2.4
```